# can't telnet via IP but can via localhost

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, localhost

I started an instance on AWS ec2 and am trying to connect via my web browser to the app on the server running on port 3000. I've also turned off iptables...

I can telnet via `telnet localhost 3000` and `telnet 127.0.0.1 3000` but can't telnet via the hostname or ip like `telnet ipaddress 3000`.

When i do that, I get a connection refused. I think this has somethign to do with my hosts file but can't figure out what. My host file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   ip-108-205-72-168
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you gave the instance a public ip, have you checked the security groups?  [AWS security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) are associated with instances and apply inbound/outbound rules.

If you have already done that then my next step would probably be to make sure that the port is bound to the correct interface(s).  `ss -tupan | grep 3000`

Comment: I'm in a private subnet but am VPN'd into it and I can ssh to the box fine with the private IP and my security groups are setup to allow port 3000...that command gives me this: `tcp    LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:3000                  *:*                   users:(("node",pid=23891,fd=12))`...looks like its just listening on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yep.  You will need to fix your configuration most likely.  `/etc/xinit.d` is where I would start.  Also, as @langgerger suggested below, make sure you are not blocking this with a local fw.

Comment: sorry.  `/etc/xinetd.d`  typo.  :)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you iptable rules is right and can accessed by ip.

Comment: maybe your telnet server do not listen on the IF which have the public ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm whether you using elastic IP over the amazon VM?

If yes, then it will do the entry in the host file automatically when you associate elastic IP to the EC2.

But if not, then need to do a manual entry.

Thanks,
SIM

Comment: yep...I'm using an elastic IP but not a public one

Comment: need to add an entry then in your EC2 instance in /etc/hosts file.